# Catch() does not catch Exceptions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am applying a development where I am implementing Spring validations and I am having the problem that when I insert an object with the property *Codigo* null, it throws an error but I can't catch it with the try-catch.

I am expecting that when it fails because of the null, I can obtain that error throw the try-catch().

**Object**

```
@Column( name = "codigo" , unique = true , nullable = false , length = 255 )
@UniqueElements( message = "El codigo debe ser unico.")
@Length( max = 255 , message = "El codigo debe ser menos a 255 caracteres")
@NotNull( message = "El codigo es requerido.")
private String codigo;


@Column( name = "motivo" , unique = false , nullable = false , length = 255 )
@Length( max = 255 , message = "El motivo debe ser menos a 255 caracteres")
@NotNull( message = "El motivo es requerido.")
private String motivo;


@Column( name = "active" , unique = false , nullable = false )
@NotNull( message = "El estado es requerido.")
private Boolean active;
```

**Service**

```
 @Transactional( rollbackFor = BusinessLayerException.class )
 public String insertMotivoBaja( MotivoBajaTO motivoTO ) throws 
 BusinessLayerException {

try {
    
    MotivoBaja motivo = super.getPersistentObject( motivoTO , MotivoBajaTOT.class );
    return super.add( motivo );
    
  }catch (Exception e) {
    
      this.logger.error( e.getMessage() );
    
      if( e.getMessage().toLowerCase().startsWith("El".toLowerCase() ) ) {
          throw new BusinessLayerException(  e.getMessage());
      }
    
       throw new BusinessLayerException( "Error al dar de alta el motivo. Por Favor intente nuevamente." );    
    }

}
```

**Error**

> org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction

> Caused by: javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'org.hibernate.validator.constraints.UniqueElements' validating type 'java.lang.String'. Check configuration for 'codigo'

**Request ( body )**

```
 {
   "codigo":null,
   "motivo":"No quiere ser mas cliente",
   "active": true 
 }
```

Comment: The exception is not happening inside your `try...catch` block but in JPA code during transaction commit.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/UniqueElements.html)

> Validates that every object in the provided **Collection** is unique

`String` is not a  `Collection`, and the exception thrown is not happening inside the `try` method, but well before it, that's why it's not being caught